# Can it be defined as inner product of two vectors?

Tags: inner-products

I have formulated something like

For $V_n$ where ${\bf x}=(x_1,x_2,x_3, \ldots,x_n)$, ${\bf y}=(y_1,y_2,y_3,\ldots,y_n)$

and I define ${\bf x} \cdot {\bf y}$ to be $(x_1+x_2+x_3+ \cdots+x_n)(y_1+y_2+y_3+\cdots+y_n)$

it seems like it works for all four axioms.

Is there mistake here?

Answer (score 2):

$\def\\#1{{\bf#1}}$An inner product should have the property that if $\\x\cdot\\x=0$ then $\\x=\\0$.  This is not true for your example (except in the case $n=1$).  For example, if $\\x=(1,-1,0,0,\ldots)$, then
$$\\x\cdot\\x=(1-1+0+\cdots)(1-1+0+\cdots)=0\ ,$$
but $\\x\ne\\0$.

Comment: when x=0, you are meaning that x=(0.0.0.0.0...0) for all xi where i->n ?

Comment: Yes, the zero vector, all components zero.

Comment: david, one more thing. What I have to do is define inner product and see whether it violates axioms in my book, where there are four axioms. 1. (x.y)=(y.x)  2.(x.y+z)=(x.y)+(x.z) 3. c(x.y)=(cx.y) 5 (x.x)>0 if x is not 0 . But, there is no such axiom that u mentioned in my book.

Comment: and besides that, does my definition satisfy 1,2,3 axioms that I just mentioned above?

Comment: oh my god so stupid I understand what you mean by that

Comment: Your definition seems to be OK for axioms 1,2,3.  The property I stated is just another way of saying your 4th axiom.

Comment: Thanks, May god bless your family and you and i love you